# Let's try to fix the "Sleep Wake failure in EFI -- Failure code:: 0xffffffff 0x0000001f"

Tags: startup, ssd, sleep-wake, crash, efi

I have had this well-known issue for a way too long time...
Now it got unbearable and I'm hoping to find help here.

### The issue

For those unfamiliar with it, here's the general description:

**Starting after** a particular software update -- presumably **a particular EFI version** -- **systems with a non-Apple SSD** **waking from sleep** (sometimes from standby or hibernation) the system **crash**es and upon reboot, a window notifying of an emergency shutdown is shown.
It has a button for generating a report with contents as in the example below

Example report from 2022-05-15 23:47:46

```
Sleep Wake failure in EFI

Failure code:: 0xffffffff 0x0000001f

Please IGNORE the below stackshot

================================================================
Date/Time:        2022-05-15 23:47:46 +0200
OS Version:       ??? ??? (Build ???)
Architecture:     x86_64
Report Version:   29

Data Source:      Stackshots
Shared Cache:     0x795000 634FC8AC-B76B-36EF-9359-7C7BCA53E6E5

Event:            Sleep Wake Failure
Duration:         0.00s
Steps:            1

Time Awake Since Boot: 34s



Process:          swd [312]
Architecture:     x86_64
Footprint:        428 KB
Start time:       2022-05-15 23:47:46 +0200
End time:         2022-05-15 23:47:46 +0200
Num samples:      1 (1)

  Thread 0x8bc    1 sample (1)    priority 4 (base 4)
  <thread QoS background (requested background), thread darwinbg, process darwinbg, IO tier 2>
  1  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 109769) [0x7fff67954cc9] 1
    1  ??? [0x10dd71454] 1
      1  ??? [0x10dd711dd] 1
        1  __stack_snapshot_with_config + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 135862) [0x7fff67ab62b6] 1
         *1  ??? [0xffffff80002bf206] 1
           *1  ??? [0xffffff8000982437] 1
             *1  ??? [0xffffff800089afc1] 1
               *1  ??? [0xffffff80002e29e7] (running) 1

  Binary Images:
        0x7fff6793a000 -     0x7fff67970fff  libdyld.dylib (750.6)                 <789A18C2-8AC7-3C88-813D-CD674376585D>  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
        0x7fff67a95000 -     0x7fff67ac1fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (6153.141.2.2) <5CDBBC06-6CA6-3432-9FDA-681047866F3E>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0184.B00, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonR9M370XItem, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, spdisplays_pcie_device, 2 GB
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1615.2)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

One or both parts of the failure code (`0xffffffff` and `0x0000001f`) appear to differ in some cases with similar descriptions, like in [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dme38s/comment/fhrkk1j) (`0x00000400 0x0000001f`, `0x0131150e 0x0000001f`), altough I am doubtful these are really the same issue.

### Affected systems

This appears to affect all hardware (the list below contains an exemplary link for each):

- [iMac/Pro](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251950365)
- [MBA](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dme38s/comment/fimsqez/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- [MBP](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251768285)
- [Mini](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250866201?answerId=252618579022#252618579022)
- and even [some](https://github.com/acidanthera/bugtracker/issues/817) [Hackintosh](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-sleep-wake-failure-in-efi-code-0xffffffff-0x0000001f.292092/), **the latter apparently with a possible solution approach of modifing boot options in BIOS!**

Although some people report similar issues appearing before Catalina, e.g:

- macOS High Sierra (10.13)

  [(different failure code 0x0131150e 0x0000001f)](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dme38s/comment/fejzzfc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- macOS Mojave (10.14)

  - [Hackintosh](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/sleep-wake-issues-mac18-3-mojave-catalina.284906/)
  - ['me too' without details](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250866201?answerId=252847304022#252847304022)

the issues there seem to be slightly different.
The majority of posts I've seen and my own experience indicate that everything started with one of the Catalina updates (some examples for 10.15.3/4 are listed) and continued until Monterey.

- [macOS Catalina (10.15)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395861/odd-os-x-behavior-when-it-goes-to-sleep-returned-to-login-said-it-shut-down-b)

  - [10.15.3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251223766?answerId=252394102022&page=2) (Differnt but possibly related issue: kernel panic on wake that can be disabled by turning off power nap)
  - [10.15.3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250866201?answerId=252115308022#252115308022) (simple 'me too' without details)
  - [10.15.3](https://www.macuser.de/threads/kein-aufwachen-aus-dem-ruhezustand.843797/post-10507785) (German forum post, apparently same issue -- identical error code)
  - [10.15.4](https://mrmacintosh.com/10-15-4-update-wake-from-sleep-kernel-panic-in-16-mbpro-2019/) (possibly related kernel panics introduced with the .4 version)
  - [10.15.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391052/os-x-catalina-seems-to-shut-down-during-sleep) (the most common version I find error reports for)
- [macOS Big Sur (11)](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/sleep-wake-issues-mac18-3-mojave-catalina.284906/)
- [macOS Monterey (12)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253741260)

### Suggested fixes that work for a lucky few

All of these I have only seen confirmed by ['worked for me' comments](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sleep-wake-failure-imac-constantly-crashes.2113844/post-30036968), I have yet to see someone actually confirm that they had this exact issue.
For me and many others **these do not work**:

- Resetting SMC (<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>)
- Resetting PRAM/NVRAM (<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  + <kbd>power</kbd>)
- Safe Boot (<kbd>⇧</kbd> during boot)
- Reinstall (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during boot, with/without disk erase)
- Reinstall older versions of the OS, not available via the App store (https://github.com/corpnewt/gibMacOS is a great tool for this!)
- [deleting sleepimage](https://mac-optimization.bestreviews.net/how-to-delete-sleepimage-on-macos/)
- many additional magic trics suggested in dubious clean-your-mac sites and stack-exchange content copiers [(that seems to have become a thing...)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here))

### 'Fixes' that are none

A large number of people have reported that disabling standby [and](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV85ogQbyts)/[or](https://eshop.macsales.com/Service/Knowledgebase/Article/26/785/NVMe-SSDs-Standby-Mode-Issue) hibernation helps, i.e:

```bash
sudo pmset -a standby 0
# and/or
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

Although, these 'fixes' appear to only work for other issues / variants of this one with different error codes.
(`0x0171260 0x0000001f` @ 1:22 in the video linked under 'and', the statement from OWC liked to in 'or' doesn't reference any error code).

**For me the above won't work.**

I have only found two dissatisfactory 'solutions' that prevent this issue:
Either I prevent sleep temporarily by running

```bash
caffeinate # my MBP must have a serious addiction by now
```

whenever I need to stop working for a moment long enough to not warrant shutting down.
Or I disable sleep completely via

```bash
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
```

The first is often forgotten, causing the issue and in rare cases (usually I have everything synched) data loss.
The second carries the risk of one day forgetting to turn off my laptop before closing the lid, putting it in a backpack and finding it fried itself when taking it out again...

### Replacements

Some people have stated that [replacing RAM](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sleep-wake-failure-imac-constantly-crashes.2113844/post-30743595) has worked for them, although I assume this might rather be a different issue.
From what it looks like, there's also the option of turning back to an [Apple SSD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lieGSblvs0U).
While the latter is probably the most satisfactory option (Yes, you can complain about Apple not making their software work for other vendors' SSDs, but then again, what would they gain from this...) but also sets you back a few bucks.

Also finding a matching SSD for some of the older models can be challenging -- I only know of second hand sales on ebay for my system.

In case someone wants to try the SSD replacement, I found the classification and compatibility notes on
https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd
very helpful!

### My current machine's state

- Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,5
- System Version:   macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15)
- Kernel Version:   Darwin 19.6.0
- Boot ROM Version: **MBP114.0184.B00**
- SMC Version (system): 2.30f2
- SSD: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8

### Idea

If I remember correctly, I did not have this issue in the first versions of Catalina I had installed, although the System Profiler only shows version 10.15.6 to be the earliest and versions as early as 10.15.4 appear to have had this issue (see **Affected systems**).

Related past installations from `system_profiler` (possibly not complete?)

| Software Name | Version | Source | Install Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gatekeeper Configuration Data | 181 | Apple | 04.06.2020 | 21:11 |
| EFICheck AllowListAll | 89 | Apple | 09.06.2020 | 20:40 |
| macOS 10.15.6 Update |  | Apple | 30.07.2020 | 22:44 |
| macOS Catalina 10.15.6 Supplemental Update |  | Apple | 19.08.2020 | 18:09 |
| macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update |  | Apple | 06.10.2020 | 17:47 |
| Device Support Update |  | Apple | 19.10.2021 | 08:24 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2021-003 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 07.06.2021 | 10:17 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2021-006 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 19.10.2021 | 08:22 |
| EFICheck AllowListAll | 123 | Apple | 28.02.2022 | 14:02 |
| EFICheck AllowListAll | 127 | Apple | 09.05.2022 | 10:52 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2022-002 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 28.02.2022 | 16:31 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2022-003 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 12.04.2022 | 18:51 |
| macOS Catalina | 10.15.7 | Apple | 15.05.2022 | 22:19 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2021-004 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 18.06.2022 | 20:13 |
| macOS Catalina Security Update 2022-004 | 10.15.7 | Apple | 18.06.2022 | 22:20 |
| macOS Installer Notification | 2 | Apple | 17.01.2022 | 09:20 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.1 | Apple | 25.01.2022 | 10:32 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.2 | Apple | 02.02.2022 | 09:59 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.2.1 | Apple | 17.02.2022 | 11:56 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.3 | Apple | 21.03.2022 | 01:56 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.3.1 | Apple | 05.04.2022 | 11:01 |
| macOS Monterey (**failed**) | 12.4 | Apple | 17.05.2022 | 00:35 |

**My current belief** is that in the course of some of these updates the EFI (i.e., Boot ROM Version) got changed and with it, the way the system and my non-Apple SSD communicate.
The current EFI version is the one listed in the oldest issue of [recommended EFI versions at the eclecticlight blog](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/04/which-efi-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using/) (These only list data up to MBP11,4, however mine (11,5) also appears to be using the same Boot ROM version as the 11,4 models, as indicated by the version string).

**If anyone is aware of a list (and trustworthy source) of older EFI versions**, the solution approach I'd be imagining would look like this:

1. Identify the most recent EFI version that does not have this issue
2. Compare it against the following versions and isolate the culprit option (for example by [comparing boot options](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/08/21/booting-the-mac-efi-firmware/))
3. Turn the offending option off like [some Hackintosh users appear to have done](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-sleep-wake-failure-in-efi-code-0xffffffff-0x0000001f.292092/)

Let me know what you think and whether I am missing some relevant clue.

## UPDATE

Yesterday I got the same error again after unplugging my fully charged mac from power for a few minutes while it was on.
When I came back it seemed to have gone into sleep despite my current power settings:

```bash
sudo pmset -g | sort
```

gives

```
 acwake               0
 autopoweroff         0
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 disksleep            10
 displaysleep         10
 gpuswitch            2
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 hibernatemode        0
 highstandbythreshold 50
 lidwake              1
 powernap             0
 proximitywake        0
 sleep                0
 standby              0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 tcpkeepalive         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
```

The only thing that's turned on is disk sleep (which hasn't been any issue for me before!).
I checked and my Catalina version string has changed from 19H15 to 19H1922, although I don't remember actively updating.

I am now disappointed enough to try an SSD switch...

Comment: I have a similar issue when my computer runs out of battery completely then this happens. It does this weird double restart and then throws the error. I was thinking maybe the internal clock battery. However, that's probably not it. If we're having similar errors it's more likely what you're suggesing an OS issue, SSD or RAM issue. I have a Macbook Pro Mid 2012 with 1TB SSD and 16 Gig's RAM. So I've added the SSD and the extra RAM. Also running the same version of the Operating system as you.

Comment: Those are some helpful data points. My situation is very similar: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012), 8 GB, 256 GB SSD. I believe it was originally 4 GB and HDD. I'm still on Catalina 10.15.7, and probably won't bother trying a newer (and officially unsupported) version until I understand this issue better. Double restarts + this issue often happen when my laptop runs out of battery, which is frequent because it's old.

Comment: Followup: I decided to upgrade to Ventura 13.4 anyway, using OpenCore Patcher. And it's working much better now.

Comment: Disable "Wake for network access" and "Enable Power Nap" appears to have worked for this user: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251950365